Do I need an inside junction box when installing an AC disconnect outside?
I'm about to install an AC disconnect (Eaton DPF221RP specifically) on my new construction wall.
I'll pop the knock-out on the back and install a cable connector, then hang the box on the outside, but do I need a junction box or anything else on the inside?
I've been planning on putting a junction box on the inside of the wall (with the opening facing the outside) and running the NM-B from the panel into the JB then out through the wall and into the disconnect, but it just dawned on me that there shouldn't be a need for it, so I want to be sure that there really isn't a need for this extra box.

This link quotes NEC 440.14
https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=1513#:~:text=2023%20Code%20Language%3A-,440.14%20Location.,air%2Dconditioning%20or%20refrigerating%20equipment.
If you're not in the U.S. that won't be relevant. Basically it says there must a disconnect within SIGHT of the outside unit ... which you'll have.
You will not need a junction box but might prefer it, if adding one makes it easier to attach conduit or sheathing you might want. In my place, the last installer ran the Romex through a window and draped it up in the joists ... so I'd say you're ahead of the game here. :)

I'm not aware of anything that would require you to have a J box inside as long as you're going right to the panel. If you're just running cable through the wall, you shouldn't need any sheathing but of course anything remotely exposed outside must be in conduit.

Interesting question. I think code says you're not allowed NM-B to outside fittings (a wet location) so having a junction box inside to transition to waterproof wires like THWN to go through a conduit stub to the cutoff might be needed.

From what I have read on here, directly through the wall into the fitting is okay, an inch or more along the outside wall is bad.

I was wondering about that, too. Do I need the inside JB to transition from NM-B to UF-B through the wall and into the disconnect? I think @crip659's comment is appropriate, though - there are many cases where a minor ~~violation is acceptable~~ exception is granted where it's a matter of inches and common sense. I don't know if this is one of those...
